# Archimedean ordering and a greatest $r_n<x\in{M}$ shows every number less than a lower bound is also a lower bound?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

This question pertains to [BBFSK Vol I](https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke), page 143.  The topic is the definition of the greatest lower bound of a non-empty set $M\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ which is bounded from below.

For $1<g\in\mathbb{N},$ let $r_n$ be the greatest integral multiple of $g^{-n}$ which is a lower bound of the set of real numbers $M.$  The claim is that the existence of $r_n$ and the Archimedean ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ proves  that every number which is less than some lower bound of $M$ is also a lower bound of $M$.

I get why $r_n$ is a lower bound of $M$, and why every number less than $r_n$ is also a lower bound of $M$.  But, for every $r_n$ there may exist some lower bound of $M$ which is greater than $r_n$.  So what, if anything, is special about $r_n$ over any other rational lower bound of $M?$

Comment: Surely the fact that every number which is less than some lower bound of $M$ is also a lower bound of $M$ follows directly from the definition of lower bound?

Comment: That's why I'm wondering if there is anything special about $r_n$ or if we just need **some** rational number from which to establish relative ordering.  I'm guessing that they are appealing to the well-ordering theorem which they proved for natural numbers a while back.

Comment: What's special about $r_n$, besides being a lower bound of $M$, is that it's pretty close to $M$. Specifically, $r_n+g^{-n}$ is (by definition of $r_n$) not a lower bound of $M$. So there is an element of $M$ in the little interval $[r_n,r_n+g^{-n})$. (A consequence of this will be that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n$ exists and is the greatest lower bound of $M$.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass If that is the intended meaning, then perhaps some nuance was lost in translation.  I will argue that your interpretation is not a statement about the existence of $r_n.$ It is, instead, a statement about the **definition** of $r_n.$  That is, the claim is about the pair $\left<r_n,r_n+g^{-n}\right>.$